# Why do I get Lexerr:unterminated quote error?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following template:

```
<!--Votez pour ce concept de bar:-->
<p ng-show="enabled('http://ballentines.herokuapp.com/{{finalist.slug}}.html') === 'novote'">Not voted</p>

<!-- Vous avez voté pour ce concept de bar-->
<p ng-show="enabled('http://ballentines.herokuapp.com/{{finalist.slug}}.html') === 'thisvote'">
    Voted for this concept
</p>

<!--Vous ne pouvez voter que pour un seul concept de bar -->
<p ng-show="enabled('http://ballentines.herokuapp.com/{{finalist.slug}}.html') === 'othervote'">
    Voted for another concept
</p>
```

When I try to run it, I get

```
Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unterminated quote at columns 8-57 ['http://ballentines.herokuapp.com/{{finalist.slug] in expression [enabled('http://ballentines.herokuapp.com/{{finalist.slug].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.11/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unterminated%20quote&p1=s%208-57%20%5B'http%3A%2F%2Fballentines.herokuapp.com%2F%7B%7Bfinalist.slug%5D&p2=enabled('http%3A%2F%2Fballentines.herokuapp.com%2F%7B%7Bfinalist.slug
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Same error here. Expecting answer on this.

Comment: fwiw (though probably not the same issue you're seeing) I got a similar Lexerr error when I had an extra "=" character in an angular attribute specification. When I dropped the extra "=" the error went away.

    <div class="container" ng-controller="TestController" ng-file-drop=="{ url: '/'+bucketSelections[0].name }">

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this error with this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tG8LN27EaAUqDqUEJzOt?p=preview).
Do you know of any other code that might also be affecting this? A directive, include, etc? What's the value of finalist.slug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-show` expects [expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) while `{{` `}}` is just shortcut for [ng-bind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) directive. In your case

```
<p ng-show="enabled('http://ballentines.herokuapp.com/' + finalist.slug + '.html') === 'novote'">Not voted</p>
```

should work.

Comment: Well no it shouldn't: you have an extra single quote before `finalist.slug` :-)

Answer (score 5):

I get this error from time to time when Chrome's Angular Batarang extension is installed. It auto updates itself and sometimes the error is present, sometimes not.

To test this, I just disable Batarang and refresh the app.

Comment: I fixed the problem by installing the [AngularJS Batarang (Stable)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang-stable/niopocochgahfkiccpjmmpchncjoapek) extension.

Comment: Yup. Batarang was not OK with a '-columnName' we were using for sorting. However, AngularJS itself was perfectly happy with it.