# AngularJS - inline css style rendering

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Is it possible / and how / to write inline css style using angular variables?

```
<div style="background: transparent url({{eventInfo.eventHeaderImg}}) top center no-repeat;"></div>
```

This is my output

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://test/eventInfo.eventHeaderImg"
```

So I see it didn't render this value.

I know it's possible to change this in controller, but is it doable with my approach?

Comment: Doesn't your `eventInfo.eventHeaderImg` variable in current `$scope` hold `'eventInfo.eventHeaderImg'` value?

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/zEtT9/

Comment: yes, when I print {{eventInfo.eventHeaderImg}} in html I get correct value.

Comment: @Djomla: In the fiddle provided above, I use `{{eventInfo.eventHeaderImg}}` in the `style` attribute as an argument to `url` (the exact same thing you do in your question). And it works fine. I think there was a bug with the `style` attribute in earlier versions of Angular. What version are you using ?

Comment: @Djomla: 1.2 what ? Try using the latest version.

Answer (score 20):

#### You should use [ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle):

an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/qT8skZzTwXjrh3Ye5mr9?p=preview

```
<div ng-style="{ background: 'transparent url({{ eventInfo.eventHeaderImg }}) top center no-repeat' }"></div>
```

Comment: Hmm Im not sure why it's not working in my case. I have correct value in variable, but it's no rendering.

Comment: ng-style="{background: transparent 'url({{eventInfo.eventHeaderImg}})' top center no-repeat;}" I got this error

"Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ''url(/8330.png?547933175)'' is unexpected, expecting [}] at column 27 of the expression"

Comment: try this: `ng-style="{background: 'transparent url({{eventInfo.eventHeaderImg}}) top center no-repeat'}"` the whole expression should be inside single quotes.

Comment: Still same.. Im getting something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272145/why-do-i-get-lexerrunterminated-quote-error

Comment: There is not reason to use `ngStyle`. See my comment under the question. If you are using interpolation (`{{}}`) it should be working with style. Unless you use an older version of Angular.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for my:

```
<div ng-style="{ 'background': 'transparent url(' + eventInfo.eventHeaderImg + ') top center no-repeat' }"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're "writing" a wrong url in your style, that's why you've got a `404` (not found) error.

According to [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YKsddedn86vzV618ON8i?p=preview), if you're `$scope` is well set up, you print the right data in `style` attribute.

Note that your `eventInfo` scope variable has to be a map/object.

Answer (score -4):

You don't need to use double curl brackets there.

Comment: Actually if you don't like to use ng-class and without the curly brackets you could use the approach explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18248437/angularjs-bind-variables-into-css-syntax