# Styling components with inline CSS - Ionic2, AngularJS

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to append an inline CSS rule for `background-image` using a dynamic variable set inside the `constructor` like so:

```
<div style="background-image: url('{{backgroundImage}}');">
  ...
</div>
```

then in my Component:

```
export class SomeComponent {

  backgroundImage = '';

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.backgroundImage = 'https://unsplash.it/200/300' ; }

}
```

However, when the element is rendered to the screen, the inline **CSS rule gets omitted.**

I tried using Angular's `ng-style`, but it returns "Can't bind to 'ng-style' since it isn't a known property of 'div'".

I also tried setting `styles` inside my `@Component` declaration as noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23289464/3284936), but this wouldn't fly in my case, as I need the `backgroundImage` variable to be dynamic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Ionic2 (or just Ionic) is built on top of **Angular** (an not AngularJS), you can do that like this:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{ background: 'url(' + backgroundImage + ')' }"></div>
```

or

```
<div [style.background]="'url(' + backgroundImage + ')'"></div>
```

Comment: 2nd one worked for me on Ionic 3 as [style.borderColor]="stat.color" with no interpolation. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that @Ruffo :)